# what is the difference between thin arrow (->) and fat arrow ( => ) in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript there are two kind of arrow function, one is => (fat arrow) and another (->)thin arrow. My understanding is => function is used to to to use this scope and internal Closure. What the -> (thin arrow ) function do?

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw -> used but last I checked there was no such thing in Typescript. Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't CoffeeScript you're talking about, which does have a difference?

Comment: I am not using CoffeScript but typescript. I tried it in my webstorm with typescript and its not showing any error in case -> function. So I am partially sure its in the typescript but I am not getting any reference about thin function for typescript

Comment: As @toskv wrote, there's no such thing as `->` in typescript. Can you please edit your question and add the code that works for you and uses that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fat arrow `=>` preserves the `this` of the enclosing context. Otherwise it behaves like a normal function expression.

The thin arrow `->` does not exist.

It sounds like you're using Webstorm, which doesn't always provide 100% accurate error information.

Comment: It actually throws the same exception as playground: "Expression expected"

Comment: `->` this is JavaScript's `.` equivalent in *Php* to access methods or properties of a Class.